# Converting Outlook E-Mails to PDFs on RHEL 7.9

Tags: linux, microsoft-outlook, pdf, redhat-enterprise-linux

How can I convert many Outlook e-mail messages to PDFs from the command line?

[This](http://www.drugdesign.gr/blog/convert-microsoft-outlook-messages-msg-to-a-linux-readable-format) is the only tool I can find for Ubuntu, but I can't find RHEL support.

There's also [Prospect Mail](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/use-outlook-email-on-linux/), but that seems to be used for viewing e-mail messages, not converting them.

Thank you, in advance!

Comment: Outlook works on  Windows platform. Convert them there and move after converted.

Comment: There are tools that work with Ubuntu, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the emails through OWA?

Go to https://outlook.office.com/mail/

Then right-click the emails and select print -save as pdf.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Alas, I can't. There's hundreds of emails that need to stay on the RHEL server. I have no access to a UI either.

Comment: Ah, cause I'm not familiar with RHEL 7.9. Maybe there are some 3-rd party tools can convert to pdf files. But it seems will pay a lot of money. I think the easiest way is to convert the file on windows.